# My INSERT INTO command doesn't work. Do you have an idea why with my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm creating a To Do List App to work on databases. I work on a former base which could show the tasks immediately after adding it. But if you restarted the node server, the data didn't save. Logic.

For instance, if you type a task and add it, it shows the task but doesn't save it. I want to add a database functionality.

This is the dependencies :

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const jQuery = require("jquery");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const pg = require("pg");
```

I'm quite sure the problem is coming from the db declarations. This is the connection :

```
const db = new pg.Client({
    host: "localhost",
    port: dbPort,
    user: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
    database: "todolist"
})
```

This is the post route (maybe an async/await is missing) :

```
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {

    let toDo = new Date(req.body.toDo).toDateString();
    console.log(toDo);


    const task = {
        title: req.body.title,
        toDo: toDo,
        done: false
    }
    tasks.push(task)
    console.log(tasks[0].title);

    try {
        db.query('INSERT INTO tasks (task_name) VALUES ($1)', [tasks[0].title.toString()]) // try function is on, but doesn't insert data.
        console.log("Data inserted.")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    res.render("index.ejs", {
        tasks: tasks,
    })

});
```

In the try/catch statement, the "Data inserted." console.log() works, it means that it tries to add to database but I don't understand why on Postgre Admin I don't see it.

The repo is here : https://github.com/sambarnades/todo/tree/develop

Hope someone could help me! Thank tou!

I tried to add the database functionnality with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Looks like the query method is a promise, so you'll need to await it. Double check the docs

Comment: You did not `commit` the transaction. Read [node pg transactions](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions). To verify check the Postgres log.

Comment: Did you ever `.connect()` the client?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I don't see a `begin` of the transaction so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: You'll need to `await db.query(…)` otherwise the `try` won't catch an error

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
import express from "express";
import ejs from "ejs";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import pg from 'pg';

const client = new pg.Client({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "todolist",
  password: "postgres",
  port: 5432,
});
client.connect();

app.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
  let toDo = new Date(req.body.toDo).toDateString();

  const newTask = [
    req.body.title,
    toDo,
    false
  ]

  const query = await client.query('INSERT INTO tasks (task_name, to_do_date, done) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);', newTask);

  res.redirect("/")
});
```

It works! Thanks for help!